# SharePoint 2016 > Textbox to enter License key disabled on App Server. Was able to enter key on Web server

Tags: 2016, license

We had installed SharePoint 2016 Server Enterprise (Trial) as a farm.
Wherein we have 1 App Server and 1 Web server. Both are VMs on same host machine. For making the installation licensed, had gone to Central Admin > Upgrade > and entered the License key on Web server. It worked as expected. However after this when tried to same on App server, found that the license textbox is disabled.
We don't know why it is so?
Is is that for a farm entering license key on 1 server is enough? Or we have to enter key on both servers? If yes how we can do it?

Have attached snap shot for reference.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The license key applies to the farm as a whole.  Each server is not individually activated with a key.

That said, you do need a SharePoint server license for each server and the appropriate Std/Std+Ent CALs for each user.

Comment: Hi Greg,
Thank you for your reply, I guess you mean to say 'That said, you do need a SharePoint server license for each server...'
kindly confirm.

Comment: Each server requires a license (there's no std/ent edition) and each client requires a CAL unless it's a pure Internet-facing scenario.

Comment: So does it mean Textbox been disabled on App server (in my case as key entered on WFE server) is expected. If not what i need to do.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the text above it represent the key you entered?  It could also be a bug as SP2013 also had that field disabled when you initially installed it with a standard key and wanted to upgrade it with an enterprise key.  All up, you only enter the key once, not once for each server in the farm.